# background-attachment : fixed; not working with background-position

Tags: html, css, background-image, fixed

I have made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjWvdm) to explain my problem:

- When the user scroll, the blue images should follow the user scroll
- The blue images should be stuck on the opposite side of the aside parts (right for the left one | left for the right one)

The pb is that

> `background-attachment : fixed;`

isn't working this the css rule

> `background-position: left 0px;`

Someone can help me by forking the codepen to show me a working implementation ?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000px;
  max-width: 992px;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

.left {
  background-image: url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0px;
  /*background-attachment: fixed; Doesn't work*/
}

.right {
  background-image: url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 0px;
  /*background-attachment: fixed; Doesn't work*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="left"></aside>
  <main></main>
  <aside class="right"></aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is this happening?

This is working as intended, when you use `background-position: fixed;` the background is positioned relative to the viewport. This means in your example the background is now aligned on the very left of the viewport outside of the `.right` element.

You can see this by positioning `.right` along the left edge of the viewport in the snippet below.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000px;
  max-width: 992px;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

.left {
  background-image: url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 0px;
  /*background-attachment: fixed; Doesn't work*/
}

.right {
  background-image: url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 0px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="left"></aside>
  <main></main>
  <aside class="right"></aside>
</div>
```

### What can you do?

There is no way to position the background relative to the element when using `background-position: fixed;` but you can achieve a similar desired result by using a `position: fixed;` pseudo element:

- Add a new selector `.left:before, .right:before` with the following rules

  - `background-image: url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png);` - The background image
  - `background-repeat: no-repeat;` - Stop the background from repeating
  - `content: "";` - Required for the pseudo element to show
  - `position: fixed;` - Set the pseudo element to be fixed relative to the viewport
  - `height: 100%;` - Make the pseudo element fill the entire height
  - `width: 100px;` - Same as the width of the background image

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000px;
  max-width: 992px;
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}

.left {
  direction: rtl;
}

.left:before, .right:before {
  background-image: url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.left:before {
  background-position: right top;
}

.right:before {
  background-position: left top;
}

.right div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="left"></aside>
  <main></main>
  <aside class="right">
    <div>content</div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

*Please note, if you intend to put other content into `.right` you will need to add `position: relative;` to the element to set the stacking context above the pseudo element (see the `div` in the snippet).*

### Why does this work?

`position: fixed;` fixes the element to a set position relative to the viewport. By not setting a `bottom`, `left`, `right` or `top` position the pseudo element stays where it is originally positioned. The background can them be applied to the element in the usual way.

Comment: Thank you so much !!
- Can I set `width: 100%;` of the .right:before (I don't know the size of the image) ?
- Can I remove the `background-position: 0 top;` of the .right:before (not the same value as your explanation and seems to work without)

Comment: Sorry, yes the `background` rules on `.right` can be removed and you should be able to change to `width: 100%;` although when you start adding extra content you may need to be aware of the stacking context.

Comment: I am sorry but it seems to not working for the left side :/ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjYvqm

Comment: Yeah, this method won't work for the left hand side. I'll have a think about what can be done for the left side. Is the `width` of the background image always unknown?

Comment: The width of the background image is always unknown :/

Comment: But what do you propose if I know the image width. :p

Comment: @FrédéricGRATI One way you can achieve the same result is to use `direction: rtl;` in `.left` - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgWqXz.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't scroll the `aside` because you scroll the `body`

You should avoid that because it's not responsive but you can get the idea of it

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 558px;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png), url(http://www.bodyacademy.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Bande_bleu1-100x500.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: left 47px top 0px, right 104px top 0px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
  width: 280px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="left"></aside>
  <main></main>
  <aside class="right"></aside>
</div>
```